# Completely Disable Apple Calendar Account

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id, calendar, gmail

I use the Android ecosystem and whenever someone with an iPhone would send me a calendar invite, it would be forwarded to my gmail account. Recently I purchased a Mac Mini & iPhone for a project and my Gmail email address is my Apple ID. However, it seems like now when friends with an iPhone invite me to an event, it does not get forwarded to my Gmail.. it gets sent to my Apple account. Is there a way to disable my Mac Mini and iPhone from intercepting any calendar event sent to my Apple ID?

Basically, I want to still have a Mac Mini and iPhone but I want any calendar invite to be forwarded to my Gmail (like before I had any apple devices).

Comment: Great question. A word of caution, changing your AppleID is often a one way street so do lots of research before you try to add a new email to an existing Apple ID or try to change primary email. Going back is often impossible and doesn’t resolve an issue, just makes things more complicated

Comment: Why not create an Apple ID just for the project? perhaps even a matching email??

Comment: @SolarMike The project needs to connect to that email unfortunately

Comment: Then the Forward functionality may be  solution.

Comment: @SolarMike How do I set up the forward?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my issue. I went to [iCloud Calendar](https://www.icloud.com/calendar/), then went to Calendar Settings > Account and changed the option for `Receive Notifications` to be `Via Email`

[image: settings changed]